# Unable to crawl data

Tags: go

I want to use the crawler to access https://bet.hkjc.com/marksix/default.aspx, but I always get a timeout error. I can't get the return data normally using postman emulation. It will only display normally under the browser.

```
tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
}
cli := &http.Client{
    Transport: tr,
}
cli.Timeout = 10 * time.Second
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
//req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
req.Header.Set("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36")
req.Header.Add("Referer", "https://bet.hkjc.com/marksix/index.aspx?lang=ch")
resp, err := cli.Do(req)
fmt.Println("err",err)
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
fmt.Println("doc",string(body))
```

Comment: Try a higher value for the timeout.

Comment: That is invalid, I tried 30 seconds, the same error